# codeigniter fetch multiple value from sub table in same query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have facing some issue while trying to fetch multiple value from sub table in same query. I have `dealdetails` and `dealImages` table , where `dealImages` can contain multiple value wrt `deal-id` from `dealdetails` table. Writing query like,

```
$dealDetailsArray       =   array();
        $this->db->select('d.dealId,d.dealTitle,d.slug,d.dealDetails,d.extraDetails,d.aditionalDetails,d.status,d.dateAdded,d.categoryId,d.dealSubCategory,d.siteId,d.dealBrandId,d.isPinned,d.priceId,d.price,d.startDate,d.startTime,d.endDate,d.endTime,d.addedTime,d.dealUrl,d.adminAffiliatePrice,d.cashbackType,d.cashbackAmountType,d.cashbackAmount,d.shippingType,d.NumberOfClicked,d.priceType,d.discountPrice,d.discountPercentage,d.deal_location,d.howtousethisoffer,d.cancellationpolicy,d.deal_submittedby,d.dealType,d.totalavailabledeals,d.numberofdealused,d.showinhomescreen,d.showinmenu,d.isHomeScreenBigDeal,di.imageId,di.imageUrl,di.thumbImage,di.imageOrder,di.status,di.dealId,di.addedOn,di.imageobjId,di.normalimageurl,di.imgobjext,di.imgobject,di.imgisdefault');
        $this->db->from('dealdetails as d');
        $this->db->join('dealImages di', 'di.dealId = d.dealId','left');
        $this->db->where('d.endTime >= ',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $this->db->group_by('d.dealId');
        $this->db->order_by("d.dealId", "desc");
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $dealDetailsArray = $query->result_array();
            $query->free_result();  
        }
        return $dealDetailsArray;
```

Which is always returning single value from `dealImages` like

```
        [deal_submittedby] => 0
        [dealType] => 1
        [totalavailabledeals] => 0
        [numberofdealused] => 0
        [showinhomescreen] => 1
        [showinmenu] => 0
        [isHomeScreenBigDeal] => 1
        [imageId] => 22
        [imageUrl] => http://localhost/codeIgniter/uploads/cover_image/storeimages/general/general_1493562480.momo.jpg
        [thumbImage] => http://localhost/codeIgniter/uploads/cover_image/storeimages/thumb/thumb_1493562480.momo.jpg
        [imageOrder] => 1
        [addedOn] => 2017-04-30 14:28:43
        [imageobjId] => 1493562480
        [normalimageurl] => http://localhost/codeIgniter/uploads/cover_image/storeimages/normal/normal_1493562480.momo.jpg
        [imgobjext] => momo.jpg
        [imgobject] => 1493562480.momo.jpg
        [imgisdefault] => 1
```

Comment: please show your table schema with dummy records..

Comment: Query returning single value from dealImages because you user group by in you query.

Comment: @NashirUddin but if will not groupby dealid and there is 10 images in dealimage table then it will return 10 value in that parent array ... if i m not wrong

Comment: You can GROUP_CONCAT in select select query for dealimage table value

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT will return comma separated value not array format , have tried that :)

Answer (score 0):

Then add GROUP_CONCAT on select query it returns value with comma(,) separated

Code like :

```
$dealDetailsArray       =   array();  
        $this->db->select('d.dealId,d.dealTitle,d.slug,d.dealDetails,d.extraDetails,d.aditionalDetails,d.status,d.dateAdded,d.categoryId,d.dealSubCategory,d.siteId,d.dealBrandId,d.isPinned,d.priceId,d.price,d.startDate,d.startTime,d.endDate,d.endTime,d.addedTime,d.dealUrl,d.adminAffiliatePrice,d.cashbackType,d.cashbackAmountType,d.cashbackAmount,d.shippingType,d.NumberOfClicked,d.priceType,d.discountPrice,d.discountPercentage,d.deal_location,d.howtousethisoffer,d.cancellationpolicy,d.deal_submittedby,d.dealType,d.totalavailabledeals,d.numberofdealused,d.showinhomescreen,d.showinmenu,d.isHomeScreenBigDeal,di.imageId,di.GROUP_CONCAT(di.imageUrl) AS imageUrl,di.thumbImage,di.imageOrder,di.status,di.dealId,di.addedOn,di.imageobjId,di.normalimageurl,di.imgobjext,di.imgobject,di.imgisdefault');  
        $this->db->from('dealdetails as d');  
        $this->db->join('dealImages di', 'di.dealId = d.dealId','left');  
        $this->db->where('d.endTime >= ',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));  
        $this->db->group_by('d.dealId');  
        $this->db->order_by("d.dealId", "desc");  
        $query = $this->db->get();  

        if($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $dealDetailsArray = $query->result_array();
            $query->free_result();  
        }
        return $dealDetailsArray;
```